# Regex: How to exclude trailing asterisk (when present)?

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I've got a some data like this:

`Scott Palk, Western District of Oklahoma*`

And want to write a regex (using REGEXTRACT) that matches only `Western District of Oklahoma`, without the trailing asterisk. But sometimes the data has no asterisk at the end, like:

`Matthew Kacsmaryk, Northern District of Texas`

Like the above, I want to match `Northern District of Texas`.

Can I write one regex expression that will work for **both** of these scenarios? I've tried `'([^,]*)\*?$'`, but that matches the asterisk too in the first example.

Using something like `'[^,]([[:alpha:]]+ ?)\*$'` also doesn't work. It matches just the last word, *and* the asterisk like `Oklahoma*`. Help!

Comment: Try `([^,*])\**$` then what you need is in first capturing group.

Comment: @revo, that matches the last *

Comment: @PoulBak It should match it otherwise it couldn't understand if it has reached the end of line and I doubt if google sheets supports lookaheads.

Comment: Oh, now I understand.

Comment: @revo It doesn't support. Supports [tag:re2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something simple like

```
^.*, ([^*]+)\*?$
```

should capture the text with or without the trailing asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture any text/space between "," and "*" you can try something like this

```
^.*,\s([\w\s]*)\*?$
```